# Get the breadcrumb directory sequence in one query using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am supposed to get the breadcrumb or directory hierarchy of a folder based on folder id.

```
ID   title      parent_id
 1   Home          0
 2   First         1
 3   Second        2
 4   Another       0
 5   Test          4
```

Based on the table above, if my current folder is *Second*, then the hierarchy should be
**Home > First > Second**

Hence, my expected result is this:

```
ID   title      parent_id
 1   Home          0
 2   First         1
 3   Second        2
```

**Case 2:** If id is 5, then the expected result is:

```
 4   Another       0
 5   Test          4
```

My query below produces up to fourth depth only.

```
SELECT *
FROM folders AS t1
LEFT JOIN folders AS t2 ON t1.parent_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN folders AS t3 ON t2.parent_id = t3.id
LEFT JOIN folders AS t4 ON t3.parent_id = t4.id
```

Is there any other way to generate the full hierarchy up to `n` depth?

Comment: check into this document https://learnsql.com/blog/query-parent-child-tree/

Comment: show how want them returned?  you can't have an arbitrary number of columns, so presumably one row per level?

Comment: @ysth I just edited my question. Please check. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would use a recursive common table expression for this (in mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+):

```
with recursive folder_hierarchy as (
    select f.id,f.title,f.parent_id,0 as level from folder f where f.id=3
    union all
    select pf.id,pf.title,pf.parent_id,level+1 from folder_hierarchy fh join folder f on f.id=fh.id join folder pf on pf.id=f.parent_id
)
select id,title,parent_id from folder_hierarchy
order by level desc
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=0fec4f257e08a09aeeb8d9ca8abdeb78)

However, I would recommend using null instead of 0 to represent no parent.